# Want to make contentless div responsive to height of adjacent div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, web-frontend

Making a Reactjs app. Referring to the code, I would like to make the height of the `colorTab` div, equal and responsive to that of the `content` div. The height of `content` must be dynamic given that I would like it to be defined by the amount of text in `tile` +  `description`, which is variable, and the width of the window.

Currently, when I omit `min-height` from `colorTab`'s CSS and simply have `height: 100%;` defining `colorTab`'s height, `colorTab` disappears. Adding the `min-height` gives it that height but then it becomes unresponsive to the height of `content` which is the goal. How do I solve this issue?

JSX:

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="colorTab" style={color}>

  </div>
  <div className="content">
    <tr>
      <td className="title">
        <a href={link}>{title}</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td className="description">
        {description}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  min-height: 48px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.colorTab {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 5px;
  min-height: 48px;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.title {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.description {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: please check your syntax.  </div className="content">

Comment: Good catch mate. Still need help though

Comment: do you need to be using `<td`> and `<tr>` ?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: I am not putting this an answer because I don't know anything about react and therefore have converted my fiddle to pure html so as a proper answer it's not great. But it will probably be what you need. Basically: use flexbox. http://jsfiddle.net/hq8v5oL1/

Comment: You can go ahead and put it as an answer because it worked like a charm. Thank you so much kind sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox will offer the functionality you need.

Put `display: flex` on your container class. And `flex: 1` on your content div. No matter how much content you place in the content div the `colorTab` div will match its height.

Example in pure HTML/CSS (no React):

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.colorTab {
  position: relative;
  width: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="colorTab">
  
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      <div class="title">
        <a>Your Title</a>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem nam perspiciatis aperiam mollitia obcaecati molestiae, consequuntur saepe repellendus cumque aliquid. Ullam reiciendis praesentium repellendus ipsam, qui illum. At, aliquid quidem. Reprehenderit eligendi voluptatem maiores deleniti id nulla, pariatur ipsa ducimus accusantium! Unde ea nostrum eligendi suscipit impedit, laborum adipisci accusamus ducimus temporibus eius inventore optio officia reiciendis porro eos assumenda numquam velit obcaecati. Perferendis, ipsum! Facilis fuga dolorum nobis nihil illo nam, voluptate suscipit excepturi sunt non. Modi perferendis ex illum eaque pariatur laudantium saepe accusantium vel, blanditiis, aperiam odit! Suscipit ullam, necessitatibus est distinctio obcaecati, odio ipsa blanditiis consequatur.
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I would absolutely recommend the `flexbox` mentioned in the other answer but...

but for some other outdated browsers which do not support it *(cough
cough looking at you, grandpa, using that same old version of IE)*... it
might be good idea to provide extra version support.

So, for answer's completion sake:
**The other option is to utilize the `tables`.**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}

.description {
  display: table-cell;
}

.colorTab {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: red;
}

// not necessary, but for esthetic reasons
.content {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="colorTab">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      <div class="title">
        <a>Your Title</a>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem nam perspiciatis aperiam mollitia obcaecati molestiae, consequuntur saepe repellendus cumque aliquid. Ullam reiciendis praesentium repellendus ipsam, qui illum. At, aliquid quidem. Reprehenderit eligendi voluptatem maiores deleniti id nulla, pariatur ipsa ducimus accusantium! Unde ea nostrum eligendi suscipit impedit, laborum adipisci accusamus ducimus temporibus eius inventore optio officia reiciendis porro eos assumenda numquam velit obcaecati. Perferendis, ipsum! Facilis fuga dolorum nobis nihil illo nam, voluptate suscipit excepturi sunt non. Modi perferendis ex illum eaque pariatur laudantium saepe accusantium vel, blanditiis, aperiam odit! Suscipit ullam, necessitatibus est distinctio obcaecati, odio ipsa blanditiis consequatur.
      </div>
  </div>
```